# Как менять высоту слайдера bootstrap 2 на чистом javascript, без jQuery?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, bootstrap

Нужно сделать слайдер с высотой равной ширине экрана. Верстаю на joomla, перепробовал кучу слайдеров для joomla, ни один не подошел. Меня устраивает стандартный слайдер bootstrap 2, решил добавить его на страницу. Для того что бы изменять высоту слайдера есть скрипт на JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(
            function ()
            {
                $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 4000, pause: 'none'});

                setInterval(
                    function ()
                    {
                        var window_height = $(window).height();
                        $('#myCarousel').height(window_height);
                    }, 250
                );
            }
        );
</script>
```

Код не работает без библиотеки bootstrap.min.js При подключении этой библиотеки код работает, но начинает плохо работать меню в Joomla, поэтому вопрос - как сделать то же самое без JQuery на Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

[Ширина/высота видимой части окна](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window#%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0)

> Свойства clientWidth/clientHeight для элемента document.documentElement – это как раз ширина/высота видимой области окна.

```
var window_height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно будет вот так:

```
function carouselFunc()
{
    //$('.carousel').carousel({interval: 4000, pause: 'none'});
    var carousel = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel");
    carousel.carousel({interval: 4000, pause: 'none'});
    setInterval(
        function ()
        {
            //$('#myCarousel').height(window_height);
            var myCarousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");
            myCarousel.height = window.innerWidth;// вся ширина окна браузера
        }, 250
    );
}
```

Про высоту окна браузера можете прочитать [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Автор у вас в заголовке вопроса один вопрос, а тело заканчивается другим, исправьте.

- Ответ 1: для этого куча справочников с примерами.
- Ответ 2: вы подключаете полную стандартную поставку bootstrap, зайдите на их сайте в разделе кастомизации выкиньте все лишнее, оставьте себе например только карусельку и подключите, по идее не будет перекрывать остальные скрипты.